Steam release speeds
When I cook a pot of food and I want to reduce it down to a thicker sauce, it takes a long time. Does blowing across the surface release more water? It seems to reduce quicker fanning the pot.

I doubt blowing on it is that effective. Using a fan/fanning it, could work.
While cooking, the hot boiling water in the food creates a vapor region above the contents of the pot that is saturated with water so that further evaporation occurs at a slowed down rate.
But when you allow cooler air to flow across the surface of the food, this displaces the saturated air and leaves the region with a reduced vapor pressure, therefore allowing evaporation at a greater rate. Thus making the food "thicker" in a smaller amount of time.
